# How to attach two pieces of carpets in a reliable way?

Tags: carpet

Since carpets here are sold in custom length, but only in fixed 4m width, one must do a bit of cut & attach here and there to cover the whole floor.

When it comes to attaching two pieces, what's the best way?

I tried common ducktape, but it did not really stick, and I likely need a durable solution so that the pieces do not move when we walk over them each day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trade name for it is... *wait for it*... [carpet tape](https://www.google.com/search?q=carpet%20tape&espv=2&biw=1024&bih=610&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx_bDoru_KAhUJdyYKHQhzDZgQ_AUIBygC&dpr=1).

[image]

This is a roll of 4" Carpet Seam Tape courtesy of [wholesaletape.com](http://www.wholesaletape.com/product.php?productid=17543&cat=24&page=1) and while although:

> This pressure sensitive tape applies quick and easy without the need of a "step on" hot iron. Made of a 42lb natural kraft paper with a fiberglass and cotton reinforced scrim it can join most carpet and wood surfaces.

I'd have to assume that most of the old carpets I've pulled out *were* hot ironed because it was nearly impossible to tear this stuff (it looked exactly like this), but maybe this works just as well.

Comment: Ok, you got me, I had no idea such thing existed :)
I'll have to look up how it is called here (not US), but I am sure I'll find it.
Thanks!